# Ставень или ставня — что говорит норма?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Редактирую текст книги, и в авторском описании встретилось слово «ставен» (р. п., мн. ч., ж. р. от «ставня»). Всегда считал, что правильно «ставней» — р. п., мн. ч., м. р. от «ставень».
Пошёл, естественно, на Грамоту.ру и в Гугл. Все словари говорят, что нормативно и так, и эдак.
Вопрос к русистам: действительно нет никакой разницы, даже оттеночной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Розенталь и др. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ,
>   ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ, 1999
>
> §146. Колебания в роде имен существительных
>
> 1.**Слова, имеющие параллельные формы мужского и женского рода.** Некоторые имена существительные употребляются в современном русском
>   литературном языке и в форме мужского, и в форме женского рода.
>   Достаточно часто параллельные формы не связаны со смысловыми или с
>   стилистическими различиями и выступают как равноправные, однако немало
>   случаев, когда одна из параллельных форм *более употребительна* в одном
>   из указанных родов:
>
> - *ставень – ставня (чаще употребляется вторая*
>     *форма; ср. у Чехова: сорвалась ставня; у Фадеева: хлопала ставня)*

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm

Пример с вариантом "ставень" (м. р. род. п):
*Я подошёл к окну и посмотрел в щель **ставня**: бледный, он лежал на полу, держа в правой руке пистолет; окровавленная шашка лежала возле него. М. Ю. Лермонтов, «Герой нашего времени», 1841 г*

Можно лишь предположить, что разные варианты когда-то связывали с особенностями конструкции (женский род: ставня - конкретизация "створки" в паре; мужской род: ставень - разновидность "щита" или "затвора" - такие синонимы приводятся в словарях).

Answer (score 1):

Это действительно параллельные формы,  как "аневризма" и "аневризм", например.

Форма "ставня" используется чаще,  она  рекомендована по умолчанию в словаре "Русская речь в эфире"для дикторов. Родительный падеж множественного числа звучит так: **ставен** (не "ставень"!).

Форма "ставень" реже звучит, но тоже является нормой . Родительный падеж в этом случае будет во множественном числе выглядеть так: ставней.

Оба варианта верны.